# Excel - Compare rows content and flag up differences in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to work this one out:

- Shift content is the routes that must be taken on a particular shift
- Driver knowledge is the routes that a particular driver knows
- Each day they get allocated a shift.

I need the "Do they know all the routes?" column to display red or green if the cells match up with their own route knowledge.

For example, if Matthew was given shift four, Matthew has declared he knows routes one through to six. His allocated shift only covers routes one, three, five and six, therefore he knows what is on his shift and the "Do they know all routes?" column would show green.

Another example, if John was given shift three, John has declared he knows route six. His shift requires him to know routes one, three and five. The "Do they know all routes column?" would therefore turn red.

I hope you can help, I have been stuck on how to work this for a good few days now :(

(I cant post images, so I pasted the image link)

http://i63.tinypic.com/2d1tnw2.png

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what I think is a dirty work around.

Using an If statement, if the two rows on the tables don't match up in any way, then the cell throws up "Skill Issue".

It does involve me having to match the shift numbers (They don't run in chronological order), but once they are in, I shouldn't have to touch it again.

=IF(B4:G4=B12:G12,"No","Yes")